# Parsing decimal value issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jsonparser

I am passing the exact Id (i.e. 123456789123456.99) from controller in JSONResult, but when I get the value in AJAX response I get Id (i.e. 123456789123456.98).

I have observed a weird behavior in JavaScript while parsing data. Please look into the below image. Can anyone please help me here to get the same Id after parsing through JSON.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a string do?

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point numbers, ..  It's not a JSON problem either..  For better handling of large numeric numbers, there are a number of BCD implementations in javascript that you might want to look into.

Comment: I believe this has to do with floating point inaccuracy, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: Perhaps this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: @Keith - Can you please provide me the link of BCD implementation in JS and the way to resolve my issue.

Comment: Are you requiring to do math's equations on these numbers, if yes, use http://mathjs.org/index.html  they have a BigNumber implementation.  Inside the JSON though, you will want to store as string like others have said.

Comment: May be this will be helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer

Answer (score 2):

The `Id` value is too big. JavaScript uses double-precision floats for numbers, and they have about 15 digits of precision. The highest integer that JavaScript can reliably save is something like 2^51. That is why the value get rounded when you parse.

However, you can work around this limitation by sending the number as a string like so:

```
var res = '{"Id":"123456789123456.99"}';
```

Comment: I don't want to add new property with string in my model. Is there any other resolution?